# All data except the image displaying from fireBase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am working on an application the user creates an account and uploads an image to the Firebase Database and then the image is displayed on a profile page. It seems to be storing the image within the database fine, but the profile page is not retrieving the image to show it. It's passing in all the other info to the page (email, username, etc.) but not the profile pic.

this is the code used to grab the data to display on the profile page:

```
if let user = DataService.dataService.currentUser {
  username.text = user.displayName
  email.text = user.email
  if user.photoURL != nil {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: user.photoURL!){
      self.profileimage!.image = UIImage.init(data: data as Data)
    }
  }
}
else {
  // No user is signed in
}
```

this is the code to store the image into firebase:

```
let filepath = "profileimage/\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid))"
let metadata = FirebaseStorage.StorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

self.storageRef.child(filepath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metadata, completion: {(metadata, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print ("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of things; first is the data var (in .putData) is not declared (in the question) so while you may see a filename if you look in your firebase console, it's may be 0 size (no bytes). Including how data is defined would help ensure it's being written correctly. Second thing is there's no code to actually read the data from the URL. The photoURL is just that, a URL, not the image itself, so you would want to use .getData to actually read the data at that URL.

Answer (score 0):

NSData(contentsOf:_) should ONLY be used for local filepaths, never a network based URL. 
Read more about why here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init

I usually create an extension on UIImageView to load images from URLs, here is an example:

```
extension UIImageView
{
    func loadImageUsingUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Then you can call it on your desired imageView:

```
yourImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(yourURL)
```